# Replace strings based on similarity

Tags: python, string, str-replace, string-comparison

I am trying to replace strings in one list with strings in another list.

```
strlist = ['D-astroid 3-cyclone', 'DL-astroid 3-cyclone', 'DL-astroid', 'D-comment', 'satellite']
to_match = ['astroid 3-cyclone', 'D-comment', 'D-astroid']
```

Expected Output:

```
str_list = ['astroid 3-cyclone', 'astroid 3-cyclone', 'D-astroid', 'D-comment', 'satellite']
```

and also output a dictionary containing the mappings

```
dict = 
{'astroid 3-cyclone':['astroid 3-cyclone', 'astroid 3-cyclone'],
'D-comment':'D-comment',
'D-astroid':'DL-astroid',
}
```

I am trying to implement it in the following way for a test case using `difflib`,

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
from pprint import pprint


def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()


strlist = ['D-astroid 3-cyclone', 'DL-astroid 3-cyclone', 'DL-astroid', 'D-comment']
to_match = ['astroid 3-cyclone', 'D-comment', 'D-astroid']
similarity = similar('DL-astroid', 'astroid 3-cyclone')
pprint(similarity)
```

Basically, if there is a similarity match of above 0.9 or 0.85, the string in `strlist` has to be replaced with string in `to_match` list. Could use two `for` loops to check whether an item in `strlist` has high similarity ratio (>0.9) with item in `to_match`. I'm not sure if this is an efficient way to implement.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: My try, I am not sure how to create the dictionary though.

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
from pprint import pprint
def similar(a, to_match):
    percent_similarity = [SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio() for b in to_match]
    max_value_index = [i for i, j in enumerate(percent_similarity) if j == max(percent_similarity)][0]
    map = [to_match[max_value_index] if max(percent_similarity) > 0.9 else a][0]
    return map


strlist = ['D-saturn 6-pluto', 'D-astroid 3-cyclone', 'DL-astroid 3-cyclone', 'DL-astroid', 'D-comment', 'literal']
to_match = ['saturn 6-pluto', 'pluto', 'astroid 3-cyclone', 'D-comment', 'D-astroid']

map = [similar(item, to_match) for item in strlist]
pprint(map)
```

Comment: Have you tried it? What was the result?

Comment: @glibdud Yes, I have added the code to my original post. Please have a look if you are interested

Answer (score 1):

You can make dictionary from the second list and apply it to the first:

```
strlist = ['D-astroid 3-cyclone', 'DL-astroid 3-cyclone', 'DL-astroid', 'D-comment', 'satellite']
to_match = ['astroid 3-cyclone', 'D-comment', 'D-astroid']
d1 = {i.split('-')[-1]:i for i in to_match}
result1 = [d1.get(i.split('-')[-1], i) for i in strlist]
result2 = {b:[i for i in strlist if i.endswith(a)] for a, b in d1.items()}
result2 = {a:b if len(b) != 1 else b[0] for a, b in result2.items()}
```

Output:

```
['astroid 3-cyclone', 'astroid 3-cyclone', 'D-astroid', 'D-comment', 'satellite']
{'astroid 3-cyclone': ['D-astroid 3-cyclone', 'DL-astroid 3-cyclone'], 'D-comment': 'D-comment', 'D-astroid': 'DL-astroid'}
```

Comment: @Akaisteph7 Sure, but I think it is possible, given the input string structure, to create such similarities using a simple grouping algorithm.

Comment: Ah yes. I misunderstood. This relies on the assumption that all the strings will always have this general structure however.

Comment: Yes, all strings will have the same general structure

Comment: @Ajax1234 I'd still prefer to do it using `SequenceMatcher` from `difflib`. There are test cases like the following `strlist = ['D-saturn 6-pluto']`, `to_match = ['saturn 6-pluto','pluto']`.Output obtained: `['pluto']` . Expected output: `['saturn-6-pluto']`