# Replacing strings in a list

Tags: python, replace

This is a follow up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57296078/replace-strings-based-on-similarity/57296302#57296302),I am trying to replace strings in one list with strings in another list.

```
import numpy as np
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
from pprint import pprint

def similar(a, to_match):
    percent_similarity = [SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio() for b in to_match]
    max_value_index = [i for i, j in enumerate(percent_similarity) if j == max(percent_similarity)][0]
    map = [to_match[max_value_index] if max(percent_similarity) > 0.9 else a][0]
    return map


if __name__ == '__main__':

    strlist = ['D-saturn 6-pluto', np.nan, 'D-astroid 3-cyclone', 'DL-astroid 3-cyclone', 'DL-astroid', 'D-comment', 'literal']
    to_match = ['saturn 6-pluto', 'pluto', 'astroid 3-cyclone', 'D-comment', 'D-astroid']
    for item in strlist:
        map = [similar(item, to_match) for item in strlist]
    pprint(map)
```

Expected output:

```
['saturn 6-pluto', np.nan, 'astroid 3-cyclone', 'astroid 3-cyclone', 'D-astroid', 'D-comment', 'literal']
```

The code works if there is no `np.nan` in `strlist`.
I want to check if a string is `nan` and return `nan` if it exists.
However, I'm not sure how to use `elif` statement in the list comprehension `map = [to_match[max_value_index] if max(percent_similarity) > 0.9 else a][0]`

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: offtopic but important hint: please do not use python keywords like `map` as variable names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write an if else in the other map function

```
map = [similar(item, to_match) if isinstance(item, str) else item for item in strlist]
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Ok then, how about changing your `similar` function to return the item itself if its type is not string?

```
def similar(a, to_match):
    if type(a) is not str:
        return a
    percent_similarity = [SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio() for b in to_match]
    max_value_index = [i for i, j in enumerate(percent_similarity) if j == max(percent_similarity)][0]
    ret = [to_match[max_value_index] if max(percent_similarity) > 0.9 else a][0]
    return ret
```

---

You can filter your `strlist` before processing it in the for-loop by

```
strlist = [s for s in strlist if type(s) is str]
```

Comment: No, I'd like to retain `nan` values. The input is actually a dataframe column and I have to replace all the values with the new list.

Comment: Ok, but try to make simplifications in your examples which do not drift too far away from your needs next time. If your input value is a dataframe, you could also e.g. simply write inline e.g.  `df['astro_stuff'][~df.astro_stuff.isna()]` to process only valid entries while preserving the dataframe as it is.